# C++ split records in a file?

Tags: c++

Im really not sure what to call this question so please sugguest a better name if you think of one!!

I have a text file that contains, for example a record like so

```
stringA:stringB:A1B2C3D4.
```

I can easily split these into records using a delimiter at the colon(:), but what im interested in breaking down further is A1B2C3D4

Say this variable is called `char code = A1B2C3D4`. How could split I this variable into further components

```
A1
B2
C3
D4
```

Comment: If you read `A1B2C3D4` into a `std::string`, you could access it char for char (`std::string::operator[]`) or use `std::string::substr()`.

Comment: One solution could be to put the string into a `std::istringstream` and then extract two characters at a time to construct the sub-strings. Or use the `substr` function of `std::string` to get two-character sub-strings at a time. Of, still using `std::string`, just get two single characters at a time to construct the sub-strings.

Comment: use regular expression or `string::substring()`.

Answer (score 1):

I assumed that each of the components has the same length.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main(void)
{
    std::string code = "A1B2C3D4";

    const int NUM_COMP = 4;  // number of components that would be splitted
    const size_t SIZE_COMP = code.size() / NUM_COMP;

    std::vector<std::string> components;
    components.reserve(NUM_COMP);

    for(int i=0; i< NUM_COMP; ++i)
    {
        std::string component = code.substr(i * SIZE_COMP, SIZE_COMP);
        components.push_back(std::move(component));
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```